Relationship between Needham's and Lee's differing definitions of the Second Fundamental Form
I have been slowly reading Lee's Introduction to Riemannian Manifolds and Needham's Visual Differential Geometry. Both texts give a definition of the Second Fundamental Form (pages 227 and 151 respectively) and I want to make sure I understand the relationship between these different definitions. $\def\tM{\widetilde{M}} \def\tg{\widetilde{g}} \def\fff{\mathrm{I}} \def\sff{\mathrm{I\!I}} \def\tff{\mathrm{I\!I\!I}} \def\X{\mathfrak{X}} \def\tnabla{\widetilde{\nabla}} \def\bu{\textbf{u}} 
 \def\bv{\textbf{v}} \def\bn{\textbf{n}}$

From Needham's:

The Shape Operator $S$ associated with the surface at the point $p$ tells us how the normal vector changes (in which direction it tips, and how fast) as we move away from $p$ along an arbitrary tangent vector $\bv$, which is no longer necessarily short, but rather has arbitrary length $\bv$. More precisely, it is simply defined to be the negative of the directional derivative of $\bn$ along $\bv$:
$$S(\bv) := -\nabla_\bv\bn.$$
[...]
When consulting older, classical works on Differential Geometry, you will encounter terms and notation that we do not employ in this book. In particular, you will certainly meet the three socalled Fundamental Forms, denoted $\fff$, $\sff$, and $\tff$. All three Fundamental Forms are symmetric functions of pairs of tangent vectors, $\bu$ and $\bv$.
\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
\textbf{First Fundamental Form:} & \ \ \ \ \fff(\bu,\bv) = \bu\cdot\bv.\\
\textbf{Second Fundamental Form:} & \ \ \ \ \sff(\bu,\bv) = s(\bu)\cdot\bv.\\
\textbf{Third Fundamental Form:} & \ \ \ \ \tff(\bu,\bv) = s(\bu)\cdot s(\bv).
\end{split}
\end{equation}

From Lee's:

[Let $(M,g)$ be a Riemann submanifold of $(\tM,\tg)$] We define the second fundamental form of $M$ to be the map $\sff: \X(M) \times \X(M) \to \Gamma(NM)$ (read “two”) given by
$$ \sff(X,Y) = \left(\tnabla_XY\right)^\perp$$
where $X$ and $Y$ are extended arbitrarily to an open subset of $M$.


First question: would Needham's definition in Lee's terminology take the following form?
Needham's Definition in Lee's Terminology: let $(M,g)$ be a hypersurface of $(\tM,\tg)$ and $N\in\Gamma(NM)$.
The Second Fundamental Form $\sff:\X(M)\times \X(M)\to \Gamma(NM)$ is defined by
$$\mathrm{I\!I} (X,Y) = g\left( -\left(\tnabla_X N\right)^\top,Y\right).$$
Second question: their definition do not match, even when $M$ is a hypersurface of $\tM$, right? Note that Needham's definition makes use of a vector field normal to the surface, while Lee's does not.

Some things that make sense for hypersurfaces do not make sense for submanifolds of arbitrary codimension. Also, you have a typo in the definition of the third fundamental form.

@TedShifrin Thank you! I've corrected the typo. Regarding codimension: in my first question I took care of specifying $M$ is a hypersurface; in my second question I 'restrict' Lee's definition to hypersurfaces. As such, I don't see how either of my questions can be answered by noting that some definitions can't be extended to arbitrary codimensions.

Lee’s definition involves the normal bundle. In the case of an (oriented) hypersurface, that normal bundle is a trivial line bundle with a distinguished section, namely $\mathbf n$. So in that case, the definitions become equivalent: Because $\mathbf n\cdot Y = 0$, $\tilde\nabla_X\mathbf n \cdot Y + \mathbf n\cdot \tilde\nabla_X Y=0$.

You just need to read a little farther in my book. On page 235, I define the scalar second fundamental form and shape operator of a hypersurface with a choice of normal vector field, and Theorem 8.13(c) shows that my definition agrees with Needham's.
